# How to get the machineName and processId of sql being run from?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to track few rows being deleted from one of the Sql Server table? I am planning to write a trigger to track from which machine or process the delete request was sent.

Is it possible to know in a Trigger in Sql Server 2005 to track the machineName and processId from which Sql is invoked?

Answer (score 2):

You can add other columns from sysprocesses as you see fit, and you need to create the ProcessLog table first.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[LogDelete] ON [dbo].[SampleTable] AFTER DELETE AS 
BEGIN 
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO dbo.ProcessLog
    SELECT 
          program_name
        , net_address
        , hostname
    FROM 
       sys.sysprocesses 
    WHERE 
       spid = @@SPID
END
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with SQL Server Profiler

https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7Asn.png

[image]
try this also :

```
SELECT sqltext.TEXT,
req.session_id,
req.status,
req.command,
req.cpu_time,
req.total_elapsed_time
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests req
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) AS sqltext
```